# Runaway argument with graphicx and MikTex (pdflatex and xelatex)

Tags: graphics, xetex, pdftex

This is a clean MikTex install today.

Minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{cover.jpg}
\end{document}
```

It fails with:

```
Runaway argument?
"cover.jpg" \edef \Gin@ext {\Gin@sepdefault \filename@ext }\ifx \Gin@ext \ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \@tempa.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

It's not the jpg - I tried with multiple jpgs, eps files, pdfs.  It's not pdflatex as xelatex does it too.  Windows 10 Pro, if that makes any difference.  It must be something really stupid, right?

Comment: Make an update in Admin and User mode. Then try again. (Even if you installed MikTeX just today there may be pending updates.)

Comment: I did that.  Still the same, sorry.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! And without the extension?

Comment: Following this bug report https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/131, I tried both rebuilding all the formats and using the hack with \def\set@curr@file#1{%...  Neither worked, and my formats are recent from the .log file.  This really does flummox me.

Comment: It's not the extension.  I suspect something deep along the lines of the packaging issue mentioned in the link above, but I've refreshed everything in user and admin and rebuild the formats.

Comment: show the complete log-file. And change cover.jpg to example-image.jpg first.

Comment: It's path lengths.  Basically it doesn't work deep in the directory structure but it does from home.  I'll post an updated question.